# Is there such expression as "Charlie someone out"?

Tags: analysis, dialogue, translation, deadwood

There is the following exchange in Deadwood series season 1 episode 3

> ...
>
> Johnny: Al?
>
> Al: Yeah.
>
> Johnny: That cherry New York dude is downstairs askin’ for ya.
>
> Al: No good. **Charlie him the fuck out**.
>
> (Johnny approaches Al’s side)
>
> Johnny: He keeps talkin’ about the Pinkertons.
>
> ...

I am interested in the expression from the title, while meaning is perfectly clear from the context I am wondering is this a real expression (meaning do people actually use it like this).
I have found two ([1](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Charlie%20Out) and [2](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Charlie%20The%20Fuck%20Up)) entries in urbandictionary, but they both are neither here nor there.

Comment: This might be better suited on one of the English Language Stack sites. It's not a phrase I've heard before.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is Charlie is sometimes replaced with Chuck and "chuck him out" does make sense here but I've never seen it used with Charlie instead.

Comment: My take on this was that an English 19th century saying, "chivvy him along/out" meaning to hurry the man out of sight, perhaps against his will, might peg Swearengen as a hoity-toity, but if he "americanizes" it into "charlie him out" ... not so much. As long as Dan and Johnny understand, well nothing more needs be said 'tween em.

Comment: @Paulie_D: Swearengen is English though, so he may be taking inspiration from cockney substitutions, in his own way. It's not quite the same, but similar enough.